# Get value tr of id inside Iframe using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I m trying to access to a table inside of a iframe using Jquery but I can´t. I need id value of (tr) inside of table but this is on a iframe and does not work.
I need to click above the tr and get the value of id.

Inside Iframe:

```
<table id="table_3">
 <tr id="value_1">
   <td>ABC</td><td>ACB</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="value_2">
  <td>FGH</td><td>DFG</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I'm using this to access:

```
<script>
 $(document).on('click', "#table_3 tr", function () {      
     alert($(this).attr('id'));          
 });
</script>
```

This works if i have the code inside of the main page but using iframe does not  work.

Comment: I need to get values from the iframe when i click on the table but does not work. I tried like a other answer but does not work.

Comment: Your edits are great but this is still a duplicate question.